# Php code to fetch data from mysql without reloading the html page

Tags: php, html

I have a form where I have to select a category, depending upon that category some search criteria fields are shown to get input from the user and then all the fields of that person are shown to enable the user to modify any field's data and resave the edited data. But when I enter data in searching criteria fields and press button to show the entire data, the page reloads and then I have to select the criteria again so that depending upon the criteria, the edited data get saved in the right data. Plz can anybody help me to stop the page from reloading..

code is::

```
<button type="submit" name="edit" id="edit" onclick="editUser()">EDIT </button>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        function editUser()
                        {
                        $empCode=$_POST['empCode'];
                        $category=$_POST['category'];
                        $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "proximitycard") or die (mysql_error ());
                        mysql_select_db("abc") or die(mysql_error());
                        if($category=='staff')
                        {
                        $sql='SELECT b.emp_code,a.name,a.father_name,a.date_of_applying,b.designation FROM person_master a, staff b WHERE b.emp_code ="'.$empCode.'" AND a.id = b.p_id and a.record_status=0 and b.record_status=0' ;
                        $result=mysql_query($sql);
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {



                        ?>
                        <span> Name </span><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo "$row[1]";?>">
                        <span> Father's Name </span> <input type="text" name="fatherName" id="fatherName" value="<?php echo "$row[2]";?>">
                        <button type="submit" name="save" id="save" onclick="updateUser()"> Update </button>

                        <?php
                        }
                        }}
                        function updateUser()
                        {
                        $empCode=$_POST['empCode'];
                        $name=$_POST['name'];
                        $category=$_POST['category'];
                        $fatherName=$_POST['fatherName'];
                        $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "proximitycard") or die (mysql_error ());
                        mysql_select_db("abc") or die(mysql_error());
                        if($category=='staff')
                        {
                        $sql='update staff b, person_master a set  a.name="'.$name.'",a.father_name="'.$fatherName.'" where b.emp_code="'.$empCode.'" and a.id=b.p_id';
                        $result=mysql_query($sql);
                        }
                        }
                        if(isset($_REQUEST['edit']))
                        {
                        editUser();
                        }
                        if(isset($_REQUEST['save']))
                        {
                        updateUser();
                        }

                        ?>
```

Comment: How?? can u plz share code to call that

Answer (score 2):

Look, I'll give you a basic pseudo example as you haven't supplied **nearly** enough context for us to work from. You'll require an AJAX request.

We'll be using [`jQuery`](http://www.jquery.com) for the [`AJAX request`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // don't know your select id so whatever
    $('select').on('change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'path_to_file.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'YOUR CRITERIA DATA TO SEND TO THE PHP SCRIPT'
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    })
});
```

Now that the request is sent, we'll need to handle it through php. (<sup>*I presume you have a script that will send/echo back the conditioned data*</sup>)

But a simple test would be sending it to a file that returns `json` (<sup>*Commonly used in ajax requests as it is awesome*</sup>).

```
<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>
```

Would send back what was posted to the PHP script. And you can verify that in the console. 
(<sup>*See the `console.log(data);` line in the ajax request above?*</sup>)